# Customize Handler context to Class name only

Tags: c#

I am able to create Custom Handlers in C#,

By adding below code to to Web.config file.

```
<handlers>
    <add 
        verb="*" path="fix"
        name="SimpleHandler"
        type="SimpleHandler"
     />    
 </handlers>
```

This leads to have a context path of http://dummy.com/SimpleHandler/fix for accessing service.

**Is it possible to customize this Context path to **http://dummy.com/SimpleHandler/** only .**

I tried to do this by putting * in the path

```
<handlers>
     <add  
        verb="*" path="*"
        name="SimpleHandler"
        type="SimpleHandler"
      />
</handlers>
```

**But it is leading to have handler called on every page load.**

please suggest something ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with routing. In the global asax:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpHandlerRoute("RoutName", "SimpleHandler", "~/Your handler.ashx");
}
```

Check [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/272258/ASP-net-HttpHandler-Routing-Support) for details.

Comment: My handler resides in fix.cs file .. So how can i do routing with it ?

Comment: Added a link to the answer. Sorry I forgot to link it earlier.